# How to show data from firebase in a picker in react native

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, picker

I am developing an app in react native, I want to show names and value in  picker that is stored in firebase. How to show data from firebase on the  picker?

NB:- I am a noob. So, If you can, Please provide a simple example.

Comment: You really need to show how you are getting your data from Firebase, and what the data looks like. You are unlikely to get a good response as you haven't added any code to your question.

Answer (score 5):

You can find basic guideline on how to use firebase database from [Firebase Realtime Database With React Native](https://medium.com/mindorks/firebase-realtime-database-with-react-native-5f357c6ee13b) article.

After getting data from it, you just need to use setState to set data and use [Picker](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker) from react native.

```
<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.language}
  style={{height: 50, width: 100}}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
  this.setState({language: itemValue})
}>
   <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />    // update this according to your firebase data collection
   <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
</Picker>
```

This is demo code for picker, you need to render `Picker.Item` as per you firebase data.

You can even use third part library called [react-native-picker](https://github.com/beefe/react-native-picker) which will display data in wheel picker for both `android` and `iOS`.

**Update**

As you want it dynamic code also, please see reference code

```
{this.state.data.map(element =>
    <Picker.Item label={element} value={element} />
)}
```

`this.state.data` is data you have set to state when you received response from `firebase`

Comment: thanks for the replay. But That is my actual question how to update the 'picker.item' using firebase data